# Final coordinates of ovals created within class definition (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As of now my program creates a canvas out of an image and creates 5 colored dots. The user is supposed to drag the dots to where they want them and close out of the tk frame.

**What I want to do is save the final coordinates of each dot when they close out of the window.**

I've found threads on class variables and on oval coordinates, but I can't tell how to isolate specific ovals for this when everything is being done within the class definition/while in a loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent,width=400,height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image='Something.gif')


        # this data is used to keep track of an 
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token((50, 100), "red","Head")
        self._create_token((100, 100), "red","Feet")
        self._create_token((150, 100), "green","Shoulder")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "green","Elbow")
        self._create_token((250, 100), "green","Wrist")

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color, part):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.P=self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags=("token",part))


    def on_token_press(self, event):
        '''Begining drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''

        #  Saving the coordinates should probably go here?
        #  How to identify which token is being un-clicked    
        #  so the coordinate can be saved in the appropriate  
        ###  variable?? I don't know

        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0


    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation of your code needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To get an item coordinates: `canvas.coords(item_id)`
- To get all your dots ids: `canvas.find_withtag('token')`
- To get the tags of a given item: `canvas.itemcget(item_id, 'tags')`

I have used all of the above in the `get_coords` function to retrieve the dots coordinates in a dictionary:

```
    def get_coords(self):  # method inside the Example class
        tokens = self.canvas.find_withtag('token')
        coords = {}
        for token in tokens:
            coords[self.canvas.itemcget(token, 'tags')] = self.canvas.coords(token)
        print(coords)  # do whatever you want with the coords
```

Then, to retrieve the coords on window closure, you can do

```
def quit():
    ex.get_coords()
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit)
ex = Example(root)
ex.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

With `root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit)`, the function `quit` is called when the user closes the window.